# how to redirected using redirection url with id after create action in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation-zurb tab feature, and rendering data from different models. When some financial gets created, then it redirects to show page with active tab defined in foundation class. How can i redirect to financial tab when some financial gets created?

project#show.html.erb

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="columns">
      <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
        <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Project Activities</a></li>
        <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Project Financial</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
        <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
          <%= render "projects/project_activities" %>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
          <%= render "financials/index" %>
        </div>
```

financials_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @financial = @project.financials.build(financial_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @financial.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_path(@project), notice: 'Financial was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @financial }
      else
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `anchor` option for url helper

```
redirect_to project_path(@project, anchor: 'panel2')
```

You need to add `data-deep-link` option to your tabs to store current state in the URL and allow users to open a particular tab at page load with a hash-appended URL

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs data-deep-link="true" id="example-tabs">
```

You can find more useful options in [docs](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/tabs.html#tabs-and-urls)

Comment: still it opens active tab after create#action on other controllers tab.

Comment: it's foundation tab so i have to also chnage selected attribute to true by id